# Unity get mouselook to be smooth and framerate independent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I've been confusing myself about `Update()` vs `FixedUpdate()` and `time.deltaTime` vs `time.fixedDeltaTime` for this situation.

I want frame-rate independent movement for the camera mouse-look but at the same time I want it to be as smooth as possible for 60 fps. For some reason, 60 fps seems slightly jittery.

My question is, do I put the function below inside of `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()`? Should the `deltaTime` variable be `time.deltaTime` or `time.fixedDeltaTime` to achieve this? Or am I doing this all wrong?

Thanks for any input.

BTW the `SmoothDamp` function below is a smoothing function based on lerp that allows for the feedback

```
void MouseLook()
{
    if (_isEscaped)
        return;

    if (!_isAllowedToLook)
        return;

    var deltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    var adjustedSensitivity = _lookSensitivity * 100f; //Keeps sensitivity between 0.1 and 10f but makes the sensitivity in math actually work

    _lookInput.x = SmoothDamp.Float(_lookInput.x, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), _lookSmoothSpeed, deltaTime);
    _lookInput.y = SmoothDamp.Float(_lookInput.y, Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), _lookSmoothSpeed, deltaTime);

    // Mouse look
    var newVerticalPitch = _verticalPitch + _lookInput.y * -adjustedSensitivity * deltaTime;
    _verticalPitch = SmoothDamp.Float(_verticalPitch, newVerticalPitch, 15f, deltaTime);
    _verticalPitch = Mathf.Clamp(_verticalPitch, -_maxVerticalLookAngle, _maxVerticalLookAngle);             //Clamp vertical look

    // Camera vertical rotation
    var newCameraRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * _verticalPitch);
    _camTransform.localRotation =
        SmoothDamp.Quaternion(_camTransform.localRotation, newCameraRotation, 15f, deltaTime);


    // Player horizontal rotation
    var newPlayerRotation = _transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(_lookInput.x * adjustedSensitivity * deltaTime * Vector3.up);
    _transform.rotation = SmoothDamp.Quaternion(_transform.rotation, newPlayerRotation, 15f, deltaTime); //Player rotation
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) and [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) are both callback functions that Unity invokes on your `Monobehaviours` at certain times during their lifetime. More specifically, `Update` is called **every frame** (assuming the `Monobehaviour` is enabled) and `FixedUpdate` is called **every physics frame**.

Physics frames are independent of graphical frame-rate and are set from within Unity to occur at a specific interval. The default is 50 times per second (in other words `FixedUpdate` runs at 50fps by default).

`FixedUpdate` is generally a function that you should reserve for your *physics-based needs* (such as using `RigidBodies` or ray-casting etc.) and most certainly **not** one to use for things such as getting user input.

Now that that is hopefully cleared up, let's address `Time.deltaTime` and `Time.fixedDeltaTime`:

`Time.fixedDeltaTime` returns the amount of time that has passed since the previous `FixedUpdate()` frame ran. Now, since we know from above that `FixedUpdate()` runs at a constant frame-rate (50 by default) this value will more or less always be the same between frames

`Time.deltaTime` similarly returns the amount of time that has passed since the previous `Update()` frame ran. Now, since `Update()` does **not** run at a constant frame-rate, but is dependent on the user's machine, this value is almost always going to be a little different each frame.

So with all of this in mind, should this go in `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()`? And should it use `Time.deltaTime` or `Time.fixedDeltaTime`?

If I've done a decent job at explaining the differences between these things, then I would expect you to now know that it ought to go in `Update()` and use `Time.deltaTime`.

I do not know what that `SmoothDamp.Float()` method is doing exactly, but by `lerping` between two positions using `Time.deltaTime` as the `t` parameter, you will ensure that no matter what the frame-rate of the machine running this is, that it will be smooth and consistent.

Comment: Hey, i appreciate the response. So, I place the function inside of update and set the deltaTime variable to Time.deltaTime. How does that explain the behavior that when my FPS is uncapped (200+) the mouselook is really really slow but when i cap it at 60 fps its very fast sensitivity with nothing else changing? That doesn't seem frame-rate independent in that case. Without a doubt its the most smooth movement in this situation but it doesn't seem fps independent.

Comment: I cannot answer that without you posting your `SmoothDamp` function I'm afraid.

Comment: I actually removed my smoothdamp from the equation for testing purposes (no smoothing at all) and im still having the issue. Here is the new test code inside of update. https://pastebin.com/mptAKukB         Is it possible that I'm not supposed to multiply the deltaTime inside the transform.rotation quaternion?

Comment: Your question seems to me to be more focused around the differences between `Update` / `FixedUpdate` and `deltaTim`e / `fixedDeltaTime`. So what exactly is it that you're trying to make your script achieve?

Comment: Nevermind i got it man thanks for the help. The issue was that i had a time.deltaTime in the wrong spot and it threw off calculations. I marked you as the correct answer. You seem to have a better grasp on this though so would you mind answering one more question? When it comes to applying friction/gravity/etc calculations on a player velocity and I intend to move the player with rbody.MovePosition inside of fixed update, should all of the calculations of the velocity be made inside of update while the move function alone is inside fixed update? Or should it all be in fixed update? Thanks

Comment: I'm delighted to hear that you figured it out! As for your question, I would personally say to read your inputs in `Update()` or `LateUpdate()` and store references to any 'calculation variables' that you might need. Then in `FixedUpdate()` I would use those variables to do any necessary calculations and apply Physics changes to the `Rigidbody`. After all, doing your calculations outside of `FixedUpdate()` would just be wasteful and inefficient seeing as you'd only be using them *inside of* `FixedUpdate()`. That way when it comes time to calculate, you have the 'latest' values from the Inputs.